# Want to change post authors using user role

Tags: wordpress, post, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, user-roles

I have a custom post type "campaign" in my WordPress site, i am using publish press plugin to assign multiple users as author to individual posts in this post type.
but now what i need is instead of selecting user one by one i can select a user role and all user associated to that role will become that post author.

Example:- i have a user role "Founder", "Manager", now i will have an select option on all post tabs where i can select user role...if i select "manager" than all user with manager role will become post author

I am expecting if there is any free plugin or i am okay with custom code